# Option to download my Facebook data missing

Tags: facebook, download

The option to download my Facebook data (a feature rolled out to *everyone* last week) is missing, from where it should be on the Account Settings page...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a feature <strike>rolled</strike>
>   **rolling** out to everyone <strike>last week</strike>

Just sit tight, I do not have it as well .With 500 M users (worst case scenario) wanting to download data I think it is safe to say that they do not want to totally destroy their servers in one go.